# Angular JS POST vs regular XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Trying to upload an image using angular's `$http.post()`

I'm setup like this, where `file` is the first file from the file input.

```
var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("content", file);
    fd.append("binary", true);
```

Running this uploads the file properly:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){alert("Done!");}, false);
xhr.open("POST", path);
xhr.send(fd);
```

But I want to use angulars $http. So I do this and it isn't uploaded properly:

```
$http({
      method: 'POST', 
      url: path,
      data: fd
    });
```

What am I missing? I've tried setting the headers to multipart and still no dice.

Comment: You can't upload files via Ajax without doing other hacky BS.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot send files via angular's HTTP service this way.  Just upload the file using XHR2, as you have done in your 2nd code block.  If you need a more comprehensive solution, perhaps an existing plug-in is in order.  You can read more about why this isn't working for you in angular in [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/MBf8qvBpuVE.).

Comment: This isn't an angular solution, but if you just want to encapsulate a code, you can try using this: https://github.com/mockenoff/HTML5-AJAX-File-Uploader